# Does JDBC do anything to protect my password and username from sniffing?

Tags: java, mysql, security, jdbc

I'm working on a front end for a database I have set up and I was wondering if I just use this code will my password and username show up in plain text if some one is sniffing?

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + address + "/table";
String user = user_Name;
String password = complete_Password;

Connection conn = null;
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    return conn;
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: JDBC definitely does not do anything. Maybe MySQL does (or has an option to do that).

Comment: Just curious to know why you are worried about packet sniffing? Is the DB server present on the internet?

Comment: I decided to do some sniffing with wireshark and it reported the user name and the db but it only put native password for the password

Comment: Yeah it is atm, I don't really know the standard procedures to put it out of reach of people while still letting people with this program that I am making use it.

Comment: if you would like to avoid password hard code in the database connectivity class ,then you could use the property class from the util package can declare name and password in it and you can access it here in the database classes with out hard coding

Comment: It's actually not hard coded I use a swing password field to get it from the user. I am more worried because this program connects over the line directly to the database.

Comment: You can verify this by using a sniffer yourself. One that is pretty powerful is http://wireshark.org

Comment: I went ahead and did that thank you for the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on how the JDBC driver is implemented, the MySQL JDBC driver will not transmit your password in clear text. You can see this happening at the [MysqlIO](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlIO.java.html) class (look for the `changeUser` method).

You can also see the various types of authentication MySQL offers (including the very unsafe clear text passwords over the wire) at it's [client-server protocol documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/authentication-method.html#packet-Authentication%3a%3aNative41).

I seriously doubt any vendor produced database driver out there will send your password data as clear text over the wire. At least I know the MySQL and PosgreSQL JDBC drivers will not do this. PostgreSQL, for instance, will generate a hash of your password and send it.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC is merely an API.  every JDBC driver implementation is different, so this would be up to the particular driver that you were using.

Comment: I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin I haven't been able to find anything as of yet that would suggest this does any encryption though.